# Usar o mesmo script para vários formulários

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Como faço para usar apenas um script para vários formulários?

```
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#formPost").submit(function() {
            var dados = $(this).serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
                data: dados,
                success: function(data) {

                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<form action="" method="POST" id="formPost">
    <input type="text" name="title" />
    <input type="text" name="body" />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

Desde já agradeço!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode invocar o `form` pela `tag`, no lugar de invocar pelo `id`, exemplo:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
...
```

Nesse caso, o mesmo script pode ser copiado (ou importado) para várias páginas com formulários de id diferentes.

Se existirem mais de um formulário por página, todos eles também serão afetados, e possuirão a mesma "submit function".

Comment: Valeu brother! Funcionou!